# how to handle printing/print queue with jquery and/or asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, windows, printing

Okay, the question is more theoretical, so there is not much code.
What I have is a page `BookingSlip.aspx` and other page `BookingDetails.aspx` that has a gridview showing the booking details, the first col of that grid is a hyperlink field linking to `BookingSlip.aspx`, passing in booking number as querystring. In the `BookingSlip.aspx` there is a button `btn_Print` on which I have simply called `Window.Print` that simply pops up the windows dialog box for printing, and when user follows the required steps (clicking okay, selecting a printer etc.) Windows (or whatever OS user is using) handles the rest. Till now everything is fine.

But what I have to do, is allow user to select multiple booking numbers in `BookingDetails.aspx` (by adding a checkbox column in the gridview, that is not a problem, I did that already) and then for all of the selected items, `BookingSlip.aspx` should execute, that is, each booking slip should be printed, with the constraint, that user is presented with the windows printing dialog just once, and once he selects the appropriate options, all items (the ones selected should be printed).

Two things come to mind.

1. For each selected items in the grid view, open `BookingSlip.aspx?BN={theSelectedBookingNumber}` and then print them all at once. the problem is with is, if user selects 10, 12 or 20, its very displeasing to eye at at once 12 pages opening in their browser. The other problem is that I would have to call `window.Print` on individual page, and windows will pop up the print dialog box 10, 12 or 20 times, (depending on items selected and pages opened) which I don't want.
2. Second is open a single page with something like `BookingSlip.aspx?BN={theFirstSelectedBookingNumber}`, print it, then don't open another page, just use `Server.Transfer` or something like that to open `BookingSlip.aspx?BN={theSecondSelectedBookingNumber}` and so on..
   The problem with this is, if I call `Window.Print` at each page transfer, the user would still be presented with a print dialog box each time, which I don't want.

So, basically I am looking for a way, where user can specify the defaults in print dialog box, and with those defaults, each (selected) item from the gridview would be printed, not the item from gridview, rather, the page `BookingSlip.aspx` would be printed for each booking number selected.

So, is there a way I can queue all these prints? Or is there any other way then the two I wrote? If I am a little bit vauge, please comment, I will clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you refactor the `BookingSlip.aspx` page so that you can pass in more than one booking number and then the page would show a booking slip for each supplied booking number?

That way you would only have to print one web page instead of many.

To make sure that each booking comes out on it's own page, you can use the CSS property `page-break-after` on a suitable container element (a `<div>...</div>` perhaps). For a basic tutorial on `page-break-after` check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp).